# Outline around toggle button in WPF

Tags: wpf, styles, togglebutton

I have some toggle buttons that control the visibility of some tabs. The buttons are styled so that they turn blue when pushed and grey when not. The problem is that when one toggle button is pushed then another the first one will switch back to grey but have a blue outline. If some other control (not one of the toggle buttons) is selected the button will turn grey without a blue outline. I don't want the blue outline.

My style is:

```
<Style x:Key="TabToggleButtonStyle" TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="lightGray"/>
    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="3" />
    <Setter Property="Padding" Value="7,2,7,2" />
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="#FF41B8F2" />
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

The toggles:

```
<DockPanel LastChildFill="False">
  <ToggleButton
      DockPanel.Dock="Right"
      Style="{StaticResource TabToggleButtonStyle}"
      Click="BtnOneClick"
      IsChecked="{Binding ElementName=_mainTabControl, Path=BtnOneTab.IsSelected}"
      Content="Agent Info"/>

    <ToggleButton
      DockPanel.Dock="Right"
      Style="{StaticResource TabToggleButtonStyle}"
      Click="BtnTwoClick"
      IsChecked="{Binding ElementName=_mainTabControl, Path=BtnTwoTab.IsSelected}"
      Content="Help"/>
</DockPanel>
```

The click commands set `IsSelected = true` on a tab.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that your problem is that the template for `ToggleButton` is using `ButtonChrome` for styling the possible states, like `IsKeyboardFocused`.

So when you uncheck a `ToggleButton` it will still have the keyboard focus (since you just clicked it) so it will still be styled as such.

The default template for `ToggleButton` looks like this

```
<ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}">
    <MS_Themes:ButtonChrome x:Name="Chrome"
                            BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                            Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                            RenderMouseOver="{TemplateBinding IsMouseOver}"
                            RenderPressed="{TemplateBinding IsPressed}"
                            RenderDefaulted="{TemplateBinding Button.IsDefaulted}"
                            SnapsToDevicePixels="true">
        <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}"
                          Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}"
                          RecognizesAccessKey="True"
                          SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}"
                          VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"/>
    </MS_Themes:ButtonChrome>
    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsKeyboardFocused" Value="true">
            <Setter Property="RenderDefaulted" TargetName="Chrome" Value="true"/>
        </Trigger>
        <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="true">
            <Setter Property="RenderPressed" TargetName="Chrome" Value="true"/>
        </Trigger>
        <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="false">
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#ADADAD"/>
        </Trigger>
    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
</ControlTemplate>
```

Removing the `IsKeyboardFocused` trigger should solve your problem (This would also require you to add a reference to PresentationFramework.Aero). But since you can't just change parts of a template (it's an all or nothing deal), you'll have to rewrite it

So the `ToggleButton` style would be

```
<Style x:Key="TabToggleButtonStyle" TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="lightGray"/>
    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="3" />
    <Setter Property="Padding" Value="7,2,7,2" />
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}"
                             xmlns:MS_Themes="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Windows.Themes;assembly=PresentationFramework.Aero">
                <MS_Themes:ButtonChrome x:Name="Chrome"
                                        BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                                        Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                                        RenderMouseOver="{TemplateBinding IsMouseOver}"
                                        RenderPressed="{TemplateBinding IsPressed}"
                                        RenderDefaulted="{TemplateBinding Button.IsDefaulted}"
                                        SnapsToDevicePixels="true">
                    <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}"
                                        Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}"
                                        RecognizesAccessKey="True"
                                        SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}"
                                        VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"/>
                </MS_Themes:ButtonChrome>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="true">
                        <Setter Property="RenderPressed" TargetName="Chrome" Value="true"/>
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="false">
                        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#ADADAD"/>
                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="#FF41B8F2" />
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

Comment: This is my 18th day on my first .Net project so bear with me if I say anything nonsensical. I tried your template and it has a couple errors, VS 2010 does not like the xmlns:MS_Themes="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Windows.Themes;assembly=PresentationFramework.Aero" reference and replaced it with clr-namespace:Microsoft.Windows.Themes;assembly=PresentationFramework.Luna. Also the Background property is read only so can't be set from xaml, so I removed it. After those changes the buttons do not have a problem with outlines but the colors are wrong. Grey / light grey instead of light grey / blue.

Comment: I did some experimenting but could not get the colors to change.

Comment: After importing Aero into the project and adding `<Setter Property="Background" TargetName="Chrome"  Value="#FF41B8F2" />` to `<ControlTemplate.Triggers>` IsChecked trigger everything works great. Thanks :)

Comment: To get the "MS_Themes" namespace to work you have to register it properly (i.e add an `xmlns:MS_Themes="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Windows.Themes;assembly=PresentationFramework.Aero"` to your root XAML node -- Expression Blend will do this for you automagically).

Answer (score 2):

Most likely your issue is the Focus Visual Style.  You can get rid of it by adding this construct to your resources:

```
<!-- StyleNoFocusRect -->
<Style x:Key="StyleNoFocusRect">
    <Setter Property="Control.Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Control}">
                <Canvas></Canvas>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Then add it to your ToggleButton style:

```
<Setter Property="FocusVisualStyle" Value="{StaticResource StyleNoFocusRect}"/>
```

That should get rid of your blue outline.

Comment: Thanks for the help but this did not work for me unfortunately

Answer (score 0):

In .net 4.0, I just added this

```
<Style TargetType="ToggleButton">
    <Setter Property="Focusable" Value="False" />
</Style>
```

It removed the outline blue when I toggle another button but the button can't be focus anymore by the keyboard.